# Why did I just encounter captcha?

Tags: support

This is the first time I can recall that I've ever had to fill out captcha on this site. It seems really strange after nearly four years to be asked to prove I'm a human. Does anybody know what might cause this?

I had left my answer open in a tab for a couple of days before updating and submitting. The asker had no reputation.

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't be able to tell you *why* it happened but I do know it's a Stack Exchange system that we have no control over. I wouldn't worry about it too much unless it happens multiple times / regularly. It's happened to me once or twice before but not for awhile now.

Answer (score 0):

While you are *probably* human, even after four years. Your account could still get compromised (hacked login details, malicious browser plugin, etc., etc.). So a regular check for this when the systems of SE detect 'suspicious' behaviour is not really weird. Like @Howdy_McGee♦ already said, don't worry if it happened just once.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what behavior may have been construed as suspicious.